# How to find the speed of a moving ball?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, home-experiment, distance

My son is doing a science fair project. He is building a small model of a hyperloop. He used Neodynam magnets to accelerate a magnetic ball. The model is only 8 inches in length. The ball moves from one end of the rail to other (8 inches distance) very fast. But we don't know how fast it went. Meaning the speed it travels with. It is less a second. We want to calculate the exact speed.

How can we find out?

Comment: Are you looking for an experimental method, or a mathematical model?

Comment: If you have an iPhone, you could record the motion of the ball using the slow-motion mode of its video camera and then analyze the video recording to get the speed. I have an iPhone 5s and it appears that the slow-motion mode is 4x slower. If you have a newer iPhone, I think that the motion can be slowed down by even more.

Answer (score 1):

Take video with a mobile phone. Then use Tracker or Video Physics to analyze the data.

Edit:

- Video Physics is an app by Vernier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugfWRPORSNg
- Tracker is a desktop program, it can be quite automatic: http://physlets.org/tracker/

Comment: what is a Tracker or Video physics. Can you give some leads about them

Comment: @basamnath I added some detail. There are other programs, or one can use more general video editing tools. Important thing is that it displays the time for each frame.